# what should be the data type for html?

Tags: html, types, arduino, nodemcu

with help of my some friend from here [@tuyau2poil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21072673/tuyau2poil) , ı could achive receive, my adc values from stm32. My new problem ı could not print these values on my html page because of data type. The value that ı saw serial port.

[image]

but ı can not see these values like here in html page because of data type. I do not know what should ı do to reflect these values like in serial port to html page.

Below is my code;

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

    int incomingByte = 0;
    //char deneme[] = "";
     char *delp;
     char *delp2;
    unsigned long tw;
    /*Put your SSID & Password*/
    const char* ssid = "ssid";  // Enter SSID here
    const char* password = "pass";  //Enter Password here
    ESP8266WebServer server(80);
    float Temperature;
    float Humidity;
     
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      delay(100);
      Serial.println("Connecting to ");
      Serial.println(ssid);
    
      //connect to your local wi-fi network
      WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    
      //check wi-fi is connected to wi-fi network
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(1000);
      Serial.print(".");
      }
      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println("WiFi connected..!");
      Serial.print("Got IP: ");  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    
      server.on("/", handle_OnConnect);
      server.onNotFound(handle_NotFound);
    
      server.begin();
      Serial.println("HTTP server started");
    
    }
    void loop() {
      if (millis() - tw > 500) {  //read serial each 0.5 sec
        if (Serial.available()) // now we have at least one character in the Serial input buffer
        {
          String incomingStr = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
          //I test this with
          //String incomingStr = "0xFF S ? ADC1=1189 ADC2=1508 S ? 0xFF S ?";
    
          if (incomingStr.indexOf("ADC1") > -1 && incomingStr.indexOf("ADC2") > -1) {  //if serial data contains ADC1 or ADC2
            char deneme[incomingStr.length() + 1];
            incomingStr.toCharArray(deneme, incomingStr.length() + 1);
           // Serial.println(deneme);           //return "0xFF S ? ADC1=1189 ADC2=1508 S ? 0xFF S ?"
            //use strtok_r function as we use two instance nested
            //create contexts for strtok_r function 
            char* t1 = deneme; //must assign any value, char* t1; alone fail to compile
            char* t2 = deneme; //idem
    
            char* token = strtok_r (deneme, " ", &t1);   //return "0xFF", "S", "ADC1=1189", etc...
            while ( token != NULL ) {
              char* token2 = strtok_r(token, "=", &t2);    //return null,null,null,ADC1,ADC2 etc...
              if (token2 != NULL ) {
                if (String(token2) == "ADC1") delp = strtok_r (NULL, "=", &t2); //return 1189
                if (String(token2) == "ADC2") delp2 = strtok_r (NULL, "=", &t2); //return 1508
                //if (String(token2) == "ADC3") delp3 = strtok_r (NULL, "=", &t2); //return 1508
                //if (String(token2) == "ADC4") delp4 = strtok_r (NULL, "=", &t2); //return 1508
              }
              token = strtok_r ( NULL, " ", &t1);
            }
            Serial.print("delp = ");Serial.println(delp);
            Serial.print("delp2 = ");Serial.println(delp2);
            tw = millis();
          }
        }
        //scan http requests each loop
        server.handleClient();
      }
    }
    
    void handle_OnConnect() {
      server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(Temperature,Humidity)); 
    }
    
    void handle_NotFound(){
      server.send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
    }
    
    String SendHTML(float Temperaturestat,float Humiditystat){
      String ptr = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html>\n";
      ptr +="<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\">\n";
      ptr +="<title>Quasi Resonant Induction Heater ADC's</title>\n";
      ptr +="<style>html { font-family: Helvetica; display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;}\n";
      ptr +="body{margin-top: 50px;} h1 {color: #444444;margin: 50px auto 30px;}\n";
      ptr +="p {font-size: 24px;color: #444444;margin-bottom: 10px;}\n";
      ptr +="</style>\n";
      ptr +="<script>\n"; 
      ptr +="setInterval(loadDoc,200);\n";
      ptr +="function loadDoc() {\n";
      ptr +="var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();\n";
      ptr +="xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {\n";
      ptr +="if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {\n";
      ptr +="document.getElementById(\"webpage\").innerHTML =this.responseText}\n";
      ptr +="};\n";
      ptr +="xhttp.open(\"GET\", \"/\", true);\n";
      ptr +="xhttp.send();\n";
      ptr +="}\n";
      ptr +="</script>\n";
      ptr +="</head>\n";
      ptr +="<body>\n";
      ptr +="<div id=\"webpage\">\n";
      ptr +="<h1>Quasi Resonant Induction Heater ADC's</h1>\n";
      
      ptr +="<p>Temperature: ";
      ptr +=String(delp);
      ptr +=" NTC</p>";
      ptr +="<p>Humidity: ";
      ptr +=String(delp2);
      ptr +=" Heatsink</p>";
      
      ptr +="</div>\n";
      ptr +="</body>\n";
      ptr +="</html>\n";
      return ptr;
    }
```

What should ı do to be able to print my datas on html page like in serial port.

Answer (score 1):

That's a very strange behavior : char array delp and/or delp2 are altered (don't know where or why) beetween var setting in loop and page creation !

to avoid this alteration, I created two global strings and stock delp arrays in them. that works fine and web page is well rendered with good values.

so :

declare global strings

```
 String strDelp, strDelp2;
```

at end of loop stock char arrays in strings

```
          Serial.print("delp = "); Serial.println(delp);
          Serial.print("delp2 = "); Serial.println(delp2);
    
          strDelp = String(delp);
          strDelp2 = String(delp2);
```

when creating page use this strings

```
          ptr += "<p>Temperature: ";
          ptr += strDelp;
          ptr += " NTC</p>";
          ptr += "<p>Humidity: ";
          ptr += strDelp2;
          ptr += " Heatsink</p>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try this tomorrow my friend, ı will say the result

Comment: My friend, ıt worked so clearly. Thank you so much for your help and exlanations

Comment: @MrElectronicEngineer thanks for your thanks but I do not really deserve these compliments because I do not see where the problem is: undoubtedly an array which empties on a variable. I hope someone more clear-cutting will find the "real" solution. In the meantime if this answer suits you, it's better than nothing. have fun !